# Which regexp is faster?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I wanted to match either `A` or `a`, which of following regexps would find it faster?

```
/[Aa]/
```

or

```
/A/i
```

*How* *many* *steps* *it* does?

Comment: There are many such sites: https://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expression+tester

Comment: @TiesonT.: I don't see performance test component anywhere. Please, show it to me.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because the question can't be answered definitively.  Or maybe because it's pointless; what you're asking about is a micro-optimization that is never going to have a noticeable effect on performance.

Comment: @AlanMoore: This question has three possible answers: `first one`, `second one` and `they are the same`. I clearly understand that it is micro-optimization. That's why I've asked for any resource, where I could test more complex examples. And notice, it was a secondary question, no one has answered on main yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking it like this:

```
function time_my_script(script) {
    var start = window.performance.now();
    script();
    return window.performance.now() - start;
}

time_a = time_my_script(function() {
    var text = 'This is a test string, make it a long one to actually test well';
    var patt = new RegExp(/[Aa]/);
    var res = patt.test(text);
});

time_b = time_my_script(function() {
    var text = 'This is a test string, make it a long one to actually test well';
    var patt = new RegExp(/A/i);
    var res = patt.test(text);
});

console.log('Time A ' + time_a);
console.log('Time B ' + time_b);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsbin.com/gasayarivu/edit?js,console

PS:
With async scripts this might be a bit harder.

Comment: Nice function. I'll collect it, if you don't mind.

Comment: You mean 'correct'? Well, I guess I don't mind XD

Comment: I meant 'collect', 'gather', 'save'.

Comment: Ooo, in that case, yes of course! That what SO is for 

Comment: You definitely want to run this a few times in a loop to have a reasonable estimate. Even though A seems to be quite a bit slower than B, the variance is quite high.

Comment: You can use http://jsperf.com/case-insensitive-regex-matching and try it on various platforms.

Comment: As you can see, the results are inconclusive, being quite platform dependent. Of course, you may want to test more scenarios (creating the each of the regexes only once rather that during the loop, with short or long strings, etc.).